# RequireJs library for all

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have a library written with RequireJs. I know about r.js for optimization.
How can I make my library usable for everyone, not just AMD/RequireJs users?

Answer (score 0):

This is how jQuery does it and the way I prefer.

*Please note this is a very simple version and jQuery is a lot more complex.*

Example:

```
library = {

  a: function(){
    // this is function a
  }

  b: function(){
    // this is function a
  }
}

// check for AMD support
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "library", [], function() {
        return library;
    });
}

// expose library globally
window.library = library;
```

Remember to replace `library` with your library's name. Your file name should also match your library's name (e.g. `library.js`).

```
// "library" should match file name
define( "library", functioin(){
  ..
});
```